# How initializes this is code with IObjectSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have this code:

```
public interface IEntityBase<T> where T : struct, IComparable
{
    T? ID { get; set; }
}
```

And,

```
public class EntityBase<T> : IEntityBase<T> where T : struct, IComparable
{
    private T? _id;

    protected EntityBase(T? key)
    {
        this._id = key;
    }

    public virtual T? Id
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set { this._id = value; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null || !(entity is EntityBase<T>))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this == (EntityBase<T>)entity);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EntityBase<T> left, EntityBase<T> right)
    {
        if ((object)left == null && (object)right == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object)left == null || (object)right == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (left.Id.Value.CompareTo(right.Id.Value) != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EntityBase<T> left, EntityBase<T> right)
    {
        return (!(left == right));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this._id.HasValue ? this._id.Value.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

too, MyContext Code:

but in ObjectSet function, appearance error messages!

What is correct syntax?

```
public class MyContext : ObjectContext
{
    private IObjectSet<Page> _pageSet;

    public MyContext(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public IObjectSet<Page> PageSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageSet ?? (_pageSet = ObjectSet<Page>());
        }
    }

    public virtual IObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : struct, EntityBase<TEntity>, IComparable
    {
        return CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

class Page:

```
public class Page : EntityBase<long>
{
    public Page(long? key)
        : base(key)
    {
    }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: in MyContext.cs Specifically in ObjectSet function, this message "EntityBase<TEntity>': cannot specify both a constraint class and the 'class' or 'struct' constraint"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line:

```
public virtual IObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet<TEntity>() 
                where TEntity : struct, EntityBase<TEntity>, IComparable
```

You are specifying that `TEntity` must be a struct *and* a reference type (`EntityBase<>` is a class, hence a reference type).  These are mutually exclusive.   What you probably want (it's hard to say without seeing CreateObjectSet) is:

```
public virtual IObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet<TEntity, T>() 
                where TEntity : EntityBase<T>
                where T : struct, IComparable
```

Note that this is just a guess based on your other code, but the main issue is that you are trying to limit a generic parameter to be both a struct and a class, and you need to fix that.

Comment: Thanks Philip Rieck, Please! look again my code above, add full code. I hope a clear vision now?

Comment: @Abdalla - You need to remove the `struct` constraint from the `ObjectSet<TEntity>` generic method. The `struct` constraint can remain on the entity itself, though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what kind of error you are getting...  Be sure that you are building targeting 4.0 Framework...